# PHP - Execute bash .sh file to remove file from different servers

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I'd like to run a PHP that contains an array of IP's, and from each IP delete an specific file.

Something like this:

```
foreach($servers as $ip){           
   shell_exec("sh /my/dir/delete.sh ".$ip." ".$file);
}
```

and in the delete.sh file I'd have something like this

```
ssh user@$1 'rm /my/dir/filespath/$2 '
```

All servers has the same path and files, also user and password
any suggestions please?

EDIT:

The PHP file that executes the sh files is in a secure administrator page, and the IP's are local IPs (192.168.1.25, 26, 27)

I'd do something like this if i'd like to remove all files from the path (as I'm doing it now)

```
ssh user@192.168.1.25 '/usr/bin/find /my/dir/filespath/* -type d -exec /bin/rm -fr {} \;'
ssh user@192.168.1.26 '/usr/bin/find /my/dir/filespath/* -type d -exec /bin/rm -fr {} \;'
ssh user@192.168.1.27 '/usr/bin/find /my/dir/filespath/* -type d -exec /bin/rm -fr {} \;'
```

But I want to delete just one specific file that could be for eg in: /my/dir/filespath/other/folder/file.txt

And as I'll add more servers or change their IP's, I need them to be variable [this is not mandatory now]

Comment: And exactly what is wrong with the current solution?

Comment: Maybe should be `/bin/sh /my/dir/delete.sh ...` instead of just sh

Comment: Are you sure there's not a better way to do this? Security-wise you're not in a good place.

Comment: well.. I need to generate the URL from a PHP in a secure page and pass it to the bash file.. What other suggestions are?

Answer (score 0):

On your remote servers you can host a file lets call it callme.php

callme.php would be soemthing like

```
<?php
exec("/bin/sh /path/to/deletefiles.sh");
echo 'OK';
?>
```

deletefiles.sh would be something like

```
#!/bin/sh 
rm -rf /path/to/file/to/delete.txt
echo 'Ok'
```

finally on your command server you can have a bash file like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
servers+=("http://1.2.3.4")
servers+=("http://1.2.3.5")
servers+=("http://1.2.3.6")
servers+=("http://www.yoursite.com")
file='/callme.php'

for i in "${servers[@]}"
do
:
  echo $i$file
  curl -s $i$file
  sleep 5
done
```

or if you would rather do the remote file calling in php

```
  <?php

 $servers[]="http://1.2.3.4";
 $servers[]="http://1.2.3.5";
 $servers[]="http://1.2.3.6";
 $servers[]="http://www.yoursite.com";

 $file = "/callme.php";

 foreach ($servers as $k => $v){
         $url = $v.$file;
         $results[] = curl_download($url);
 }
 var_dump($results);

 function curl_download($Url) {
        if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
            die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
        }
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }
   ?>
```

It might not be the best way to do it , but it works...the above code I just quickly wrote out, so some of the code might need finessing and you will need to make sure all your files have proper permissions.

Comment: I have to pass the path/file to the bash file, that's generated in the php file.. that's where I'm having troubles, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: If you pass the path to the php script as an argument?

Comment: Tried that, as in the example

Answer (score 0):

** SOLVED **

I did this request from administrator

```
if($file){
    $res = file_get_contents("http://[current server IP]/delete.php?token=12345&p=".$file);
    echo $file;
}
echo $res;
```

And the delete.php file has this

```
if($_GET['token']!='12345') exit();

$ips = array(192.168.1.25,192.168.1.26,192.168.1.27);

$file = $_GET['p'];
$file = str_replace(array('../','*','./'),'',$file);
if($file != ""){
    $command = '"/bin/rm -f /my/dir/filespath/'.$file.'"';
    foreach($ips as $ip){
        echo shell_exec('ssh user@'.$ip.' '.$command);
        sleep(1);// sleep 1 sec for letting the command time to delete the file (could be less)
    }
}
exit();
```

Works perfectly!
of course with more security on the delete.php file, it's just an example version

Thanks for all!